# Dynamic product creation in drupal commerce

Tags: commerce

Say you want to make a product 'blend'. Keeping it simple, say that there are 3 products your store sells. product 1 contains only X and costs $7.00 per Kg. Product 2 contains 40% X, 60% Y, costs $2.00 per Kg. Product 3 contains 30% X, 20% Y, and 50% Z and costs $6.00 per Kg.

Its easy enough to run this through a linear algebra equation and find out that X = $7 per KG, Y = $2, and z = $7.

So for instance, The customer would select his blend. He would like a ratio of 1:2:4, and would like 50 Kgs of it.

The question I have is, how do you go about selecting that ratio, and applying the quantity as well. Its almost as if you have multiple quantities in effect now.